# Facebook Canvas App Page -- Can I change it to the Fan Page?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, sharing, facebook-page, facebook-canvas

First up, apologies for my non-technical-ness. I've looked and looked for an answer to this, but had no luck.

My site has a FB App for the purposes of grabbing the auth token so people can share stuff they create on my site right to their FB wall. The app just lets the site grab the token so we don't need to ask people to login to FB over and over.

On FB we have a canvas page to go with this app, but all it does is load our webpage in an iFrame on it (and it looks sorta crappy there).

Is there a way to change the Canvas Page to our FB Fan Page? This way if people click on our "app" from their own wanderings about FB they'll be directed to a FB fan page rather than our page looking weird in FB.

Again, I apologize if this question is way simple. I'm new. If someone has an answer for me and could use puppets to explain-- that'd probably help.

Thanks so mcuh!

Answer (score 0):

This is an obnoxious method but you can redirect the visitors to your Facebook Page when your Canvas Page is loading by checking the URL.

First you have a function that gets the URL of your Canvas Page.

```
function checkPage()
{
    $pageURL = 'http';

    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on")
    {
        $pageURL .= "s";
    }
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80")
    {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
    else
    {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
    return $pageURL;
}
```

Then you check if the URL contains "fb_source" which appears in every Canvas Page, if it does then you redirect them to your desired location.

```
    $currentUrl = checkPage();

    if(strpos($currentUrl,'fb_source') !== false)
    {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        top.location.href = "URL HERE";
    </script>
    }
```

Comment: I see! Thank you -- I wish there was a less obnoxious way! I can't have the only website that would like to be able to do this, right?